# Why my xcode 6 break on crash?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, debugging, crash

I have some error in my app, 
It report in console:

```
exc:*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

but it just crashed and terminated, just didn't break on the crash line of code.

Is it a bug or something wrong on my settings ?

I know what is the problem of my code. I just want to know why xcode not break at the line of the code, not just terminated the app running.

Xcode 6.1   Mac OSX 10.10

Comment: it not in Xcode problem , u were used array in some view controller, it calculating the empty array

Comment: This has got nothing to do with Xcode. You will need to check your array for its value.

Comment: I know what is the problem of my program, but I want to xcode check that exception and stop at the line of code, not just terminated the app. @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in your code, you are trying to access objects within an array but the array is empty. Before accessing elements of array, just check if array is empty or not by using [myArray count].

Comment: I know what is my problem. I want to know why my xcode 6 didn't break on the line of the code, it just terminated the app running

Comment: When the program execution detected memory access in array beyond allocated limit, it threw an NSRangeException. As this exception was not handled in the program, it continued to travel up the chain of calling functions till it reached the main function and it terminate the app there. If you put the code (where you are accessing array objects) within try and catch blocks, you can capture this exception within your code and handle accordingly.